# how to use HTTP over all computer? on windows and ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, ubuntu, proxy

I'm using a HTTP proxy on firefox, something like proxy.mit.it:8080.

I can use firefox to access network.

Now I hope other applications on my laptop can also use the proxy to access internet.

I tried:

Control panel -> Internet options -> connections -> LAN setting and fill the proxy server, but it doesn't work.

are there any workarounds? thanks! I'm using windows 7
also I'm using ubuntu

Comment: Unless your applications are "proxy aware" then this won't work... there are some applications available that can _help_ make an application proxy aware, but I have no idea apart from, say, Microsoft's (now defunct) TMG that has a Windows client that can make non-proxy aware applications work over a proxy.

Comment: @BigChris how about Ubuntu?

Comment: You say you are using an HTTP proxy, but you want all applications to use this proxy. But many/most applications don't use HTTP.

Comment: @BigChris this is not true. For example firewalls can enforce proxying without applications being aware of it. There will probably be ways how to enforce this fw behaviour on localhost.